Followed documents/sites are missing when migrating SP2013 MySites
We are currently migrating (testing) our SP 2013 farm to 2016.
I was able to successfully upgrade the Search, Managed Metadata and User Profile Service Applications. I also added and upgraded one of our 10 content databases for our intranet web app (https://intranet.company.com).
I also upgraded our MySite Web App with its content database (https://my.company.com).
All sites and services (seem to) work fine.
When I open the MySite with my normal user I do see all the people and tags I am following. However, I can no longer see the documents and sites that I follow like in the 2013 farm. (FYI: Some but not all documents and sites I follow are stored in the content database that I upgrade to SP2016.)

Is there any (timer) job I need to run in order for those numbers to come back?
Where is this information stored (database wise)?
What am I missing here?
Thanks in advance!
